# which one is a better practice, storing login status bar html code in view or model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have a login status bar in the header template, where it shows "login" when the user did not log in, and shows the user's name once he logged in.

I'm confused in how this if/else logic should be performed. I could had the login/not-login html code stored in the user model, had the controller handle and if/else to grab the code from the model, then pass it to the header template.  Or I could had both the login/not-login code typed into the header template, and the controller to do the if/else to generate a true/false flag, and then pass this flag to the view.

Which one is a better practice?

Comment: "html code stored in the user model" --- model layer should not be aware of anything related to the presentational layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never add the html to the model. The whole and sole purpose of the model is to fetch data. You should add a if-else condition in your header view.

When a user logs in, create a session in the model, I mainly store userid, first name and lastname.

In the header view check if the session exists, if it exists show the user is logged in with his/her name or else display a login button.